# When reviewing edits it's not always clear if it's an answer or a question

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

When reviewing [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) it is not always clear to me if it's an answer or a question. Would it be possible to make it clearer? Or did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you review an answer, the text over the author says *answered*, while in the case of questions, it says *asked*.

[image: answer]

[image: question]

The problem is with Community Wiki posts, for which neither *answered*, nor *asked* is shown.

I am not sure it is worth doing it, but maybe (considering the CW case), a question could be marked with a Q right under the question score, and an A could be used for answers.

Comment: Ah there it is. If the answer doesn't fit into one screen though, scrolling is needed. I think it would be useful to also have an indicator at the head of the suggested edit.